# Scheme/Racket - Undefined Function; Cannot use before initialization

Tags: syntax, scheme, racket, sicp

Currently going through SICP, and near the end of the first chapter, they ask you to program a value for pi, with 
`pi/4 = (2 * 4 * 4 * 6 * 6 * 8 * ...) / (3 * 3 * 5 * 5 * 7 * 7 *..)`

I have the following functions defined:

```
;Term and Next are both functions, a and b are the range of the product
(define (product term a next b) 
  (if (> a b) 1
      (* (term a) (product term (next a) next b))))
```

and

```
(define (pi-approx n)
  (define (square x) (* x x))

  (define (num-prod ind) (* (* 2 ind) (* 2 (+ ind 1)))) ; calculates the product in the numerator for a certain term
  (define (denom-prod ind) (square (+ (* ind 2 ) 1))) ;Denominator product at index ind

  (define num (product num-prod 1 inc n))
  (define denom (product denom-prod 1 inc n))

  (* 4 (/ num denom))) ;;Resulting value
```

When I run this code in DrRacket, I get the following error:
`num-prod: Undefined; Cannot use before initialization`, even though I initialize num-prod a couple of lines before I use it.

What am I doing wrong syntactically?

Comment: Worked fine for me as soon as I added `(define inc add1)`. Are you using the REPL or the definitions area?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the difference between the two is, but I'm using the top part of the editor... Here's what it looks like: [link](https://imgur.com/a/m2R0A). Side note, I did have the `(define (inc x) (+  x 1))` code, so I'm reasonably certain that wasn't part of the problem.

Comment: Small breakthrough! I asked around and something that fixed the issue was using `#lang racket` as opposed to `#lang sicp`... I'm not really sure why that would change anything, but any insight would be welcome!

Comment: it probably grouped all the internal defines into one `letrec`, causing the error. what is meant there instead is a `letrec` for the first 3 defines, then a `let` for the next two. just never use internal `define`s, it's a meaningless convenience syntax sugar anyway, the real thing is `let`/`letrec`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the top Google results for the question, so I thought I'd add some more detail:

In most Scheme implementations (such as R5RS), there is no guarantee of the order in which your definitions are parsed. In other words, they are not parsed sequentially. Yes, you defined `num-prod` a few lines before, but it's entirely possible that `num` is compiled first, hence the error.

In Racket, lambdas are compiled to `letrec*` operators instead of `letrec`, meaning that there *is* a guarantee of sequential parsing. That's why changing languages helped.

Answer (score 2):

Since I am also currently going through SICP and ran into the same error, I thought I'd mention what I think is the intended solution, since the question is in the section before `let` and `lambda`.

This error is mentioned briefly in footnote 28 in the first chapter:

> Embedded definitions must come first in a procedure body. The management is not
>   responsible for the consequences of running programs that intertwine definition and
>   use.

`num-prod` is being used inside another definition, so the program actually is intertwining definition and use, even though it looks like the definitions all come before the body.

Possible solutions (without `let` and `lambda`) are to avoid defining `num` and `denom`, replacing them with the `product` expression, or to define `num` as a function with an argument, and put `num-prod` as the argument in the body:

```
(define (num terms) (product terms 1 inc n)) 
(define (denom terms) (product terms 1 inc n)) 
(* 4 (/ (num num-prod) (denom denom-prod)))
```

Comment: a cleaner-looking solution is `(define (num n) (product num-prod 1 inc n))`, `(define (denom n) (product denom-prod 1 inc n))` and then `(* 4 (/ (num n) (denom n)))`.